# Why does my trap does not work?

Tags: bash, bash-trap

I have written below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15

function_signalr()
{
date
date | awk '{printf "%-15s\n", $2}' 
}

trap "function_signalr" 10
```

When I start the process by "process &" it runs, the PID is given.
I do kill -10 PID, but my trap does not work. The process is killed, but the trap did not sprung. No date message is given. I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

Your `trap` doesn't work because the shell doesn't know about it yet.

You need to define the `trap` function, set the `trap` and then write your code.

```
#!/bin/bash

function_signalr()
{
date
date | awk '{printf "%-15s\n", $2}' 
}

trap "function_signalr" 10

# Code follows now
sleep 15
```

Moreover note that `sleep` is blocking which implies that if you do `kill -10 PID` then the `trap` wouldn't execute until `sleep` is done.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the order of the script and now after sleeps completes the date is executed. Is it possible to terminate the sleep and execute the trap immediately or do I always have to wait for the previous command to complete?

Comment: @user3214667 I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  As mentioned above, `sleep` is blocking so `trap` won't be executed while you're sleeping.  But you could put the `sleep` in a loop in order to execute the `trap` earlier: `for ((i=1;i<=15;i++)); do sleep 1; done`

Comment: I am just doing a bash course and some parts are tricky. Thank you for your help.